# Trying to remove an unregistered UserDefaults observer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, observers, userdefaults

I'm new to Swift and iOS programming, so excuse my lack of knowledge...

I have a TabBar controller and one of the tabs' view controller registers an observer in its `viewDidLoad()` method like this:

`UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "interests", options: .new, context: nil)`

I am trying to remove the observer in the `deinit()` method like this:

`UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "interests")`

However, unless I have gone into that tab before, I get this error: `Cannot remove an observer for the key path "interests" because it is not registered as an observer`.

I understand that if I don't go into the tab `viewDidLoad()` won't be called but I don't know a better place to add the observer. I don't get this error if I have gone into this view controller. Can you tell me if there is a better place to do that or if I'm doing something else wrong? Thank you.

**EDIT** Here is my full view controller

```
class InterestsViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "interests", options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "interests")
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        // updating the UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: are you targeting and iOS lower than iOS 9.0?

Comment: I am not targeting iOS lower than iOS 9. Also, I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: then check my answer, is no longer needed to remove the observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver

If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method.

if your app targets below iOS 9.0 then you can call the register/unregister on `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try this

Comment: Turns out I have to support devices with iOS lower than 9. I tried your suggestion. However, there is a problem. I am editing the `interests` from another view controller and this won't trigger the changes in the `InterestsViewController`. How do I go about this?

Comment: There are a lot of approaches, you could use `Bond` (a cool reactive library) with a reactive signal that your controllers will listen to, or you can add to your deinit method the check `if isViewLoaded { unregister here }` and register your observer in viewDidLoad again